# How to properly configure two usb to ethernet adapters in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, networking, usb, ethernet

We have a setup, where we are using two usb to ethernet adapters to connect a computer with a HIL (Hardware in the Loop).

Computer A -> USB-to-Ethernet-Adapter 1->Ethernet cable->Ethernet-to-USB-Adapter 2-> HIL (Linux)

How must we properly configure Adapter 1 and Adapter 2 using the Windows 11 system configuration. Actually, it seems to be the case, that only the first adapter can be configured properly from the windows side. And we also don't know how to configure the second adapter from the HIL side.

Up to now we are not able to ping the HIL from the Computer A.

Does anyone here has experiences with these kind of adapters and maybe how to configure the ethernet adapter 2 in Windows 10? What can we test in order to ensure proper function of these adapters?